# Removing all spaces from the beginning of lines

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk

```
      1 147.31.124.135
      1 147.31.9.135
      1 147.32.123.135
      1 147.32.123.136
      1 147.32.124.135
      1 77.236.192.69
      1 86.49.86.108
      1 86.49.86.109
```

Hello. I have file in this format with many spaces at the beginning of every line and i wold like to remove those spaces from beginning and printed all fields using  awk or sed.

RESULT:

```
1 147.31.124.135
1 147.32.123.135
1 147.32.123.136
1 147.32.124.135
1 77.236.192.69
1 86.49.86.108
1 86.49.86.109
```

Comment: The second line is missing in your result, is that correct?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use this `sed` command to remove leading whitespace (spaces or tabs)

```
sed 's/^[ \t]*//' file
```

Use `sed -i` to modify the file in-place.

Comment: Worked for me. Just wanted to add that for running on macOS you need to use this sed -i'.bak' 's/^[ \t]*//' file

Answer (score 9):

You can even use POSIX character class `[:space:]` which will handle all whitespaces (`\t`, `\r`, `\n`, `\v` etc):

```
sed 's/^[[:space:]]*//g' file
```

Comment: Won't this also remove empty lines?

Comment: No. The substitute with "nothing" will take care of it. To delete only empty lines: `sed '/^$/d' file`

Comment: Fantastic. Works with BSD sed and GNU sed.

Answer (score 5):

The sed command

```
   sed 's/^ *//'
```

should work.

Explanation: `^` indicates the start of a line, and `*` indicates zero or more spaces. These are replaced by nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Use awk command,

```
bash-3.2$ cat input
      1 147.31.124.135
      1 147.31.9.135
      1 147.32.123.135
      1 147.32.123.136
      1 147.32.124.135
      1 77.236.192.69
      1 86.49.86.108
      1 86.49.86.109
bash-3.2$ awk 'sub(/^ */, "")' input
1 147.31.124.135
1 147.31.9.135
1 147.32.123.135
1 147.32.123.136
1 147.32.124.135
1 77.236.192.69
1 86.49.86.108
1 86.49.86.109
```

Answer (score 0):

You can even use POSIX character class `[:space:]` which will handle all whitespace (`\t`, `\r`, `\n`, `\v`, etc.):

```
sed 's/^[[:space:]]*//g' file
```